# How to send email in nodemailer without SMTP using Gmail?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

We are trying to send email from Gmail using nodemailer. Initially, we used the scope "mail.google.com".Google asked us to remove the scope "mail.google.com" we cannot able to send mail. they are recommending not to use SMTP/IMAP. How to do that using nodemailer?

I am using the below snippet to send mail

```
function sendMail(inp,emailData) {
let mailData = {
    from: inp.from, // **
    to: inp.to, // **
    subject: inp.subject, // **
    body: inp.html, // **
    attachments: inp.attachments || [],
}
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getTokens(emailData)
        .then(tokens => {
            let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: "gmail",
                debug:true,
                auth: {
                    type: "OAuth2",
                    user: mailData.from,
                    clientId: ClientId,
                    clientSecret: ClientSecret,
                    refreshToken: tokens.refreshToken,
                    accessToken: tokens.accessToken
                }
            });

            const mailOptions = {
                from: mailData.from,
                to: mailData.to,
                subject: mailData.subject,
                generateTextFromHTML: true,
                html: mailData.body,
                attachments: mailData.attachments
            };
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, result) => {
                if (error) reject({status:204,error});
                else resolve(result);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject({status:204,error});
        });
}); }
```

What's wrong with this code and what the google want us to do with removing SMTP/IMAP?